# Insert into two table foreign key and primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database namely `reservations` and `guests`. The rows are as follow:

**Reservation:**

- Reservation id
- Property Id
- Checkin date
- Checkout date
- Price

**Guest**

- Guest id
- Reservation id
- Guest name
- Guest address

Using a form that contains the reservation details and the guest details at the same time.

How can I run the insert query so that the auto generated reservation id(auto-increment in database) can also be inserted into the guest table at the same time?

This is what I have so far. I changed my code using last_insert_id()

```
INSERT INTO reservations
   SET Checkin date= '24/05/2018', checkout date = '29/05/2018';
INSERT INTO guests 
   SET reservation id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
       guest name = guest name
```

Comment: first execute/insert details to reservation table(get last inserted id).insert to guest table

Comment: add what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First insert to reservation table

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sqlR = "INSERT INTO Reservation(firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
$rStatus = $conn->query($sqlR);
$res_id = $conn->insert_id;
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email,res_id)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com',$res_id)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Prepared statements should be implemented with dynamic input values in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can insert the data into the Reservation table, based on the last inserted id, you can use the value for the column Reservation id for the table Guest. Also, please maintain foreign key constraints, so as on update and delete operations of Reservation, simultaneous operations are performed on the Guest table.
To get the last inserted id,

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   $last_id = $conn->insert_id; //gives the last inserted id
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I have to insert the data in both table at the same time? How can I pass in the reservation id?

Comment: You cannot insert the reservation id in the Guest table until it is generated, and it will be generated only after insertion of data in the Reservation table, so it will be a back to back process. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Prepared statements should be implemented with dynamic input values in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Run the insert query first with the insert_id function and then use that insert_id to run the second insert query